# Jenkins archive single file not working

Tags: windows, jenkins

I'm trying to archive a zip file in Jenkins using the `archiveArtifacts` step  like this:

```
archiveArtifacts 'publish\\archive.zip'
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Archiving artifacts
>
> ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "publish\archive.zip". Configuration error?
>
> ERROR: ‘publish\archive.zip’ doesn’t match anything: ‘publish’ exists but not ‘publish\archive.zip’

The file definitely exists. If a tack an asterisk onto the end of the path like this:

```
archiveArtifacts 'publish\\archive.zip*'
```

the step works fine and the file is archived but why is this necessary?

Comment: Did you try: `archiveArtifacts 'publish/archive.zip'` (forward slash)?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you have non readable char at the end of the filename or elsewhere in your script. I used to get some confusing script errors when writing scripts on windows and putting them on a linux environment. In IntelliJ you can change theese via file->line seperators->unix.